# Hallar nodo padre de un árbol en Prolog

Tags: prolog, árboles, árboles-binarios

Estoy empezando con Prolog y tengo la siguiente duda. No busco una respuesta inmediata si no una **explicación de cómo proceder** para resolver al ejercicio ya que no sé como podría empezarlo, aunque tengo las nociones básicas de Prolog.

La duda es la siguiente:

Se define un árbol binario en Prolog de la siguiente manera:

```
   A4 = [[[[[],1,[]],5,[]],
    7,
    [[],3,[[],4,[]]]],
    6,
    [[[],10,[]],
    8,
    [[[],9,[]],11,[[],2,[]]]]]
```

Cuyo aspecto es el siguiente 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi duda es, haciendo uso únicamente de los siguientes constructores y selectores

```
vacio([]).
raiz([_,N,_], N).
hi([HI,_,_],HI).
hd([_,_,HD],HD).
hazarbol(R,HI,HD,[HI,R,HD]).
```

Cómo puedo definir un predicado  `padre(N,Abn,P)` de manera que por ejemplo:

```
?- padre(3,A4,P).
P=7
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero tienes que comprobar si la raíz de la rama izquierda o derecha es el nodo que buscas, si es así, devuelves como padre el nodo raíz del árbol:

```
padre(N,Abn,P) :- hi(Abn,HI), raiz(HI,N), raiz(Abn,P).
padre(N,Abn,P) :- hd(Abn,HD), raiz(HD,N), raiz(Abn,P).
```

Después, recursivamente, se busca el nodo por las ramas izquierda y derecha:

```
padre(N,Abn,P) :- hi(Abn,HI), padre(N,HI,P).
padre(N,Abn,P) :- hd(Abn,HD), padre(N,HD,P).
```

Comment: Ok, entiendo el planteamiento pero cuando en prolog escribo por ejemplo `padre(9,hazarbol(11,9,2,[9,11,2]),P).` el resultado es false. ¿ A qué se puede deber esto? Gracias

Comment: Prolog utiliza una variante de la resolución SLD como mecanismo operacional. Está unificando el segundo argumento como un término `hazarbol(11,9,2,[9,11,2])`, no evaluando el predicado `hazarbol/4`, y por lo tanto no estás proporcionando un árbol válido. Utiliza `padre(9, [[[],9,[]],11,[[],2,[]]], P)`.

Comment: Gracias por contestar tan rápido. He estado mirándome la resolución SLD y ahora entiendo el funcionamiento y me están saliendo los ejercicios :D

Comment: Una pregunta: Si quisiera sacar la descendencia de un nodo tal que por ejemplo `descendencia(5,A4,Des).`  de como resultado `D=[[[],1,[]],5, []]` cómo tendría que plantearlo?

Comment: Si el nodo raíz es el nodo que buscas, devuelves el propio árbol: `descendencia(X,[L,X,R],[L,X,R]).`. En caso contrario, buscas recursivamente por los hijos izquierdo y derecho: `descendencia(X,[L,_,_],D) :- descendencia(X,L,D).` y `descendencia(X,[_,_,R],D) :- descendencia(X,R,D).`. Si tienes nuevas preguntas sobre Prolog, sería mejor marcar esta como resuelta y abrir una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias ! Ya he marcado la respuesta como correcta pero no tengo suficiente reputación aún para que se muestre creo. De todas maneras el resto de preguntas las abriré en un hilo distinto ^^

Comment: Hola de nuevo, he abierto una pregunta nueva en este enlace a ver si me podrías ayudar que estoy bastante atascado. Gracias. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/73870/hallar-lista-de-nodos-de-un-%c3%a1rbol-binario-en-prolog/73875#73875