# Hallar lista de nodos de un árbol binario en Prolog

Tags: prolog, árboles, árboles-binarios

Buenas,

Quiero hallar la manera de poder devolver una lista con todos los nodos de un árbol en prolog.

Se define un árbol binario en Prolog de la siguiente manera:

```
A4 = [[[[[],1,[]],5,[]],
    7,
    [[],3,[[],4,[]]]],
    6,
    [[[],10,[]],
    8,
    [[[],9,[]],11,[[],2,[]]]]]
```

Cuyo aspecto es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi duda es, haciendo uso **únicamente** de los siguientes constructores y selectores

```
vacio([]).
raiz([_,N,_], N).
hi([HI,_,_],HI).
hd([_,_,HD],HD).
hazarbol(R,HI,HD,[HI,R,HD])
```

Cómo puedo definir un predicado `listadenodos(Abn,L)` de manera que por ejemplo:

```
?- listadenodos(A4,L).
L=[2,9,11,10,8,4,3,1,5,7,6]
```

La solución que se me ha ocurrido aunque aún no funciona es:

```
descendencia(X,[L,X,R],[L,X,R]).
descendencia(X,[L,_,_],D) :- descendencia(X,L,D).
descendencia(X,[_,_,R],D) :- descendencia(X,R,D).

listadenodos([],[]).
listadenodos([[],X,[]],[X]).
listadenodos(Abn,P) :- raiz(Abn, N), descendencia(N,Abn,D), listadenodos(D,P).
```

No busco una respuesta inmediata si no una **explicación de cómo proceder para resolver al ejercicio** ya que no sé como podría empezarlo, aunque tengo las nociones básicas de Prolog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias formas de recorrer un árbol (ver [Recorrido de árboles](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recorrido_de_%C3%A1rboles)):

- **Preorden**. Visitar raíz, árbol izquierdo, árbol derecho.
- **Inorden**. Visitar árbol izquierdo, raíz, árbol derecho.
- **Postorden**. Visitar árbol izquierdo, árbol derecho, raíz.

Por ejemplo, para visitar un árbol en preorden. En el caso base de un árbol vacío se devuelve una lista sin elementos:

```
listadenodos([],[]).
```

Para el caso general, se devuelve una lista con la raíz como cabeza y la concatenación de los recorridos en preorden de los arboles izquierdo y derecho como cola:

```
listadenodos([L,X,R],[X|Xs]) :- 
    listadenodos(L,Ls),
    listadenodos(R,Rs),
    append(Ls,Rs,Xs).
```

Los recorridos en inorden y postorden se pueden definir de forma similar.

El predicado `append/3` forma parte del estándar de Prolog y no suele ser necesario definirlo, en cualquier caso se suele definir como sigue. La concatenación de una lista vacía `[]` y cualquier lista `X` es la propia lista `X`, y la concatenación de una lista (con cabeza `H` y cola `T`) con otra lista `X` es la lista formada por la cabeza `H` y la concatenación de `T` y `X` como cola.

```
append([],X,X).
append([H|T],X,[H|S]) :- append(T,X,S).
```

Comment: Gracias de nuevo, esta solución funciona perfecta

Comment: Una curiosidad, si quisiera combinar el predicado **descendencia** con el predicado **listadenodos** para obtener la lista de nodos de una descendencia como se podría hacer ? Gracias.

Comment: Lanza el objetivo `?- descendencia(X,A,D), listadenodos(D,N).`, o crea un nuevo predicado `p(X,A,N) :- descendencia(X,A,D), listadenodos(D,N).`.

Comment: Al final lo he resuelto así `listadedescendientes(N,Abn,L):- descendencia(N,Abn,Des), listadenodos(Des,L). 
` Gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

Teniendo la siguiente funcion auxiliar `concatenar` para el armado de la lista:

```
concatenar([],L,L).
concatenar([X|M],L,[X|Z]):-concatenar(M,L,Z).
```

Caso base: arbol con unicamente la raiz, retorna lista de unicamente la raiz

```
listadenodos(tree(A,[],[]),[A]):-!.
```

Predicado para cuando tiene hijo izquierdo, concatena a la raiz el reusltado de listadenodos del subarbol izquierdo

```
listadenodos(tree(A,X,[]),S):-listadenodos(X,P), concatenar([A],P,S).
```

Predicado para cuando tiene hijo derecho, concatena a la raiz el reusltado de listadenodos del subarbol derecho

```
listadenodos(tree(A,[],X),S):-listadenodos(X,P), concatenar([A],P,S).
```

Predicado para cuando tiene tanto subarbol derecho como izquierdo no nulos, invoca a los dos predicados anteriores

```
listadenodos(tree(A,X,Y),W):-listadenodos(X,P),listadenodos(Y,R),concatenar([A],P,U), concatenar(U,R,W).
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por contestar, pero no sé si tu respuesta es válida ya que sólo está permitido usar los constructores y selectores definidos arriba.

Comment: Acabo de probar tu solución mmartinez7 y no funciona. El output que obtengo es el siguiente `listadenodos([[[],3,[]],4,[[],1,[]]],L).` `false`

Comment: Disculpas, habian algunos errores en la solucion que te di, edite la respuesta.

Comment: Acabo de comprobar ahora la solución tuya y funciona gracias :)