# Obtener lista de nodos de un árbol binario numérico en Prolog

Tags: prolog, árboles-binarios, árboles

Estoy comenzando con Prolog y no soy capaz de resolver un ejercicio muy simple con árboles.

En este caso, se trata de una implementación de árboles (árboles binarios numéricos en este caso) como listas, del siguiente modo:

```
[]                       % Representa un árbol vacío.
[[[],2,[]],1,[[],3,[]]]  % Representa un árbol con hijos.
```

El segundo árbol mostrado anteriormente se representa gráficamente de la siguiente forma:

```
  1
 / \
2   3
```

Quiero conseguir un programa Prolog que tras ejecutar una consulta del tipo `?- escribe_arbol(1,[[[],2,[]],1,[[],3,[]]],L).` me devuelva la lista L con las hojas del árbol **ordenadas por niveles**, tal que así `L = [1,2,3].`.

Otro ejemplo, con más nodos, sería `?- escribe_arbol(1,[[[[],4,[]],2,[[],5,[]]],1,[[[],6,[]],3,[[],7,[]]]],L).`. En dicho caso, el resultado debería ser `L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7].`.

Para ello, necesito una serie de constructores y selectores de tipo, y los cuales se indican al principio del siguiente código:

```
va([]).                % Árbol vacío
ra([_,N,_], N).        % Nodo raíz
iz([HI,_,_],HI).       % Hoja izquierda
de([_,_,HD],HD).       % Hoja derecha
ar(R,HI,HD,[HI,R,HD]). % Árbol

escribe_arbol(_,ABN,_) :- va(ABN).                 % Caso base, árbol vacío.
escribe_arbol(R,ABN,L) :- ra(ABN,R).               % Nodo raíz.
escribe_arbol(R,ABN,L) :- iz(ABN,HI), de(ABN,HD).  % Nodo con hijos.
```

Mi principal problema es **cómo hacer que vaya construyendo la lista L** para que al ejecutar la consulta, por ejemplo, `?- escribe_arbol(9,[[],9,[]],L).` muestre no sólo `true .` como hasta ahora, si no `L = [9]` también.

**Edición:**

Esta pregunta no está duplicada respecto [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/73870/hallar-lista-de-nodos-de-un-%C3%A1rbol-binario-en-prolog) otra entrada, puesto que se trata de devolver una lista L por niveles, como se describe en el enunciado tras la edición (en negrita). En el otro post, se devuelve una lista que contiene los nodos realizando una búsqueda en profundidad por preorden.

Comment: La idea es la misma, pero en esa solución no se hace uso de los constructores, o me equivoco? Tampoco he conseguido hacer funcionar `append/3`.

Comment: No es necesario utilizar dichos predicados, no aportan nada si se utiliza el patrón adecuado. En cualquier caso, puedes cambiar `[L,X,R]` por una variable `A` e integrarlos. Respecto a `append/3`, depende del entorno que utilices (SICStus Prolog, Swi-Prolog, ...) pero debería estar definido. De lo contrario, en esa misma respuesta se proporciona su definición.

Comment: En primer lugar, gracias por tu ayuda. El hilo que comentas se parece mucho, pero no es exactamente lo que busco. De hecho, es culpa mía por no explicarlo bien, y por ello, voy a editar la consulta.

Al ser un ejemplo pequeño el que pongo en el ejemplo parece que sí funciona pero lo que busco es devolver una lista con los nodos por niveles. Es decir, para el siguiente árbol `[[[[],4,[]],2,[[],5,[]]],1,[[[],6,[]],3[[],7,[]]]]` el resultado debe ser `L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`, esto es, primer nivel, segundo nivel y por último, tercer nivel, y así sucesivamente.

Comment: He abierto esta otra [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/80001/devolver-lista-de-elementos-de-un-%C3%A1rbol-binario-n%C3%BAmerico-por-niveles), ya que, al no estar bien explicada ha sido marcada por muchos usuarios como duplicada.