# Devolver lista de elementos de un árbol binario númerico por niveles

Tags: prolog, árboles-binarios, árboles

Abro una nueva consulta ya que la [anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79898/obtener-lista-de-nodos-de-un-%C3%A1rbol-binario-num%C3%A9rico-en-prolog), por error mío, ha sido marcada como duplicada por [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/73870/hallar-lista-de-nodos-de-un-%C3%A1rbol-binario-en-prolog) otra. La diferencia es que en este caso se pretende devolver la lista por niveles y no mediante una búsqueda en profundidad con preorden.

Un ejemplo sería `?- escribe_arbol(1,[[[[],4,[]],2,[[],5,[]]],1,[[[],6,[]],3,[[],7,[]]]],L).`. En dicho caso, el resultado debería ser `L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7].`.

- Nivel 1: [1,...]
- Nivel 2: [...,2,3,...]
- Nivel 3: [...,4,5,6,7]

Mi código Prolog es el siguiente:

```
escribe_arbol(N,ABN,L):- explora_hijos(N,ABN,L).

explora_hijos(R,[],[]).
explora_hijos(R,[HI,R,HD],[R|Rs]).
explora_hijos(_,[HI,R,HD],[R|Rs]) :-
    explora_hijos(R,HI,HIs),
    explora_hijos(R,HD,HDs),
    append(HIs,HDs,R).
```

El resultado es `L = [6|_5626].` por lo que no está funcionando del todo bien.

Answer (score 0):

La solución la he conseguido manteniendo dos listas dependientes una de la otra por la posición de sus elementos, una para mantener la lista con los nodos obtenidos mediante búsqueda en profundidad por preorden (rama de la izquierda primero), y la segunda llevando la cuenta de en qué nivel del árbol se encuentra en cada momento.

Posteriormente utiliza el algoritmo de ordenación [insert sort](http://kti.mff.cuni.cz/~bartak/prolog/sorting.html), modificado para este caso, para ordenar la lista de niveles, haciendo la misma manipulación en ambas listas.

```
escribe_arbol(ABN,NS) :- explora_hijos(ABN,N,L,0), insert_sort(L,N,LS,NS).

explora_hijos([],[],_,_).
explora_hijos([[],R,[]],[R|Rs],[N|Ps],N).
explora_hijos([HI,R,HD],[R|Rs],[N|Ps],N) :-
    N2 is N + 1,
    explora_hijos(HI,HIs,PIs,N2),
    explora_hijos(HD,HDs,PDs,N2),
    append(HIs,HDs,Rs),
    append(PIs,PDs,Ps).

insert_sort(List,List2,Sorted,Sorted2):-i_sort(List,List2,[],[],Sorted,Sorted2).

i_sort([],[],Acc,AccO,Acc,AccO).
i_sort([H|T],[HO|TO],Acc,AccO,Sorted,SortedO):-insert(H,HO,Acc,AccO,NAcc,NAccO),i_sort(T,TO,NAcc,NAccO,Sorted,SortedO).

insert(X,XO,[Y|T],[YO|TO],[Y|NT],[YO|NTO]):-X>Y,insert(X,XO,T,TO,NT,NTO).
insert(X,XO,[Y|T],[YO|TO],[X,Y|T],[XO,YO|TO]):-X=<Y.
insert(X,XO,[],[],[X],[XO]).
```

La ejecución en Prolog tiene la siguiente forma:

```
?- escribe_arbol([[[[[],1,[]],5,[]],7,[[],3,[[],4,[]]]],6,[[[],10,[]],8,[[[],9,[]],11,[[],2,[]]]]],NS).
NS = [6, 8, 7, 11, 10, 3, 5, 2, 9|...] .
```

Answer (score -2):

[image: nevesito que me imprima los niveles de ese árbol]
Si A representa el árbol del ejercicio 3:
lista_nivel(A,2,L).
L=[2,6,9]